# Let $A$ be a $4\times4$ matrix with real entries and eigenvalues $1$, $-1$, $2$ and $-2$, then which of the following statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $B$ is a matrix defined as $B=A^4-5A^2+5I$, where $I$ is a $4\times4$ identity matrix, then

1. $\det(A+B)=0$
2. $\det(B)=0$
3. $\operatorname{tr}(A+B)=4$

From the given conditions, I could only conclude that trace of matrix $A$ is $0$, and the value of determinant of matrix $B$ is $-11$. Now how to calculate the trace of matrix $B$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\operatorname{tr}A=4$? The trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry trace of matrix A is zero , I missed seeing negative sign so now how to proceed calculating further

Comment: Use linearity of the trace and the fact that if the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_i$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=\sum_i\lambda_i^n$.

Comment: plz tell what is wrong in my approach , I calculated the determinant of matrix B ,Now I got is as -11, so now we know that product of eigen values is equal to determinant of a matrix so now since 11 is a prime number so the only diagonal values can be -1 ,1 ,-1 and -11 so as to give product =-11 and these are my eigen values so trace of matrix B =-12 , what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Show how you came up with $-11$. Also, why do you think that the eigenvalues of $B$ must be integers?

Comment: determinant of A^4 =64 , since determinant of A is 4 , so determinant of A^2=16 , so |B|=|A^4|-5|A^2|+5|I| , so 64-80+5=-11

Comment: Determinants aren’t linear in that way—the determinant of a sum isn’t equal to the sum of the determinants and $\det cM=c^n\det M$ when $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you might like better. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then from
$$
B = A^4 - 5A^2 + 5I,
$$
we compute
$$
Bv = (\lambda^4 - 5 \lambda^2 + 5)v.
$$
Hence $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue 
\begin{equation}
\mu = \lambda^4 - 5 \lambda^2 + 5.
\ref{1}
\end{equation}
Since we know the eigenvalues of $A$,
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 &= 1 \\
\lambda_2 &= -1 \\
\lambda_3 &= 2 \\
\lambda_4 &= -2,
\end{align*}
this tells us the eigenvalues of $B$. They are 
\begin{align*}
\mu_1 &= 1 \\
\mu_2 &= 1 \\
\mu_3 &= 1 \\
\mu_4 &= 1
\end{align*}
if you do the computation using \eqref{1}. Using the facts that

> - The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues,
> - The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues,

We can compute the quantities in 2. and 3. this way. (In computing 3., we also use the fact that trace is a linear function.)

However, the determinant is not a linear function! Nonetheless, we can compute the quantity in 1. because $B$ and $A$ have common eigenvectors; hence its eigenvalues are found by adding corresponding eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. That is, $(A+B)v = Av + Bv = \lambda v + \mu v = (\lambda + \mu)v$. Then multiplying $(\lambda_1 + \mu_1) \cdots (\lambda_4 + \mu_4)$ to find $\det(A+B)$ gives $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $$P(x) = (x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2) = x^4-5x^2+4,$$ therefore $B=P(A)+I$. For the third equation, you can use linearity of the trace and the fact that if the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\lambda_i$, then $\operatorname{tr}(M^k)=\sum_i\lambda_i^k$, but it’s much simpler if you take advantage of the above expression for $B$.

---

*Update:* Knowing this, the determinants can be found by inspection. By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, $P(A)=0$, therefore $B=I_4$ and $\det B=1$. Similarly, $\det(A+B)=\det(A+I)=0$ because $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. The trace of $B$ can be computed directly using properties of the trace, i.e., $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}B &= \operatorname{tr}A^4-5\operatorname{tr}A^2+5\operatorname{tr}I_4 \\
&=(1^4+(-1)^4+2^4+(-2)^4)+5(1^2+(-1)^2+2^2+(-2)^2)+5\cdot4,
\end{align}$$ but it, too can be found by inspection once the expression for $B$ has been simplified.

Comment: I calculated trace of A^4 as (-1)^4+(1)^4+(2^4)+(-2)^4 =34 , trace of A^2=(-1)^2+(1)^2+(-2)^2+(2)^2 =10 , and trace of identity matrix is 3 , so overall trace of matrix B becomes 34-50+15=-1 , is it wrong ?

Comment: @radhika It’s wrong. You’re working with $4\times4$ matrices.

Comment: I am getting confused now , You told to use the property of tr(A^k)=summation of eigen values raised to the power k , and value of k is 4 for matrix A ^4 and 2 for matrix A^2 ,plz correct me

Comment: @radhika That part’s fine. You got $\operatorname{tr}(5I_4)$ wrong, as MooS pointed out above.

Comment: Ya I got thanksss

Answer (score 2):

After suitable base change (take eigenvectors of the distinct eigenvalues of $A$), we have

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Not that hard to answer these questions now, right?

Comment: Why did u consider A as diagonal matrix ?

Comment: Because $A$ is diagonalizable...

Comment: And how did you conclude this ?

Comment: A $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable, since we easily have a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: Can u plz tell why is this approach wrong ? I calculated trace of A^4 as (-1)^4+(1)^4+(2^4)+(-2)^4 =34 , trace of A^2=(-1)^2+(1)^2+(-2)^2+(2)^2 =10 , and trace of identity matrix is 3 , so overall trace of matrix B becomes 34-50+15=-1 , why is it wrong ?

Comment: The trace of the identity matrix is $4$, we have $4 \times 4$ matrices.

Comment: @radhika $A$ isn’t necessarily a diagonal matrix, but it is diagonalizable, so that it’s similar to a diagonal matrix—$A=M\Lambda M^{-1}$. The $M$’s and their inverses will mostly cancel in a polynomial in $A$. You’ll be left with $M$ times a polynomial in $\Lambda$ times $M^{-1}$, which won’t affect the determinants, so you may as well take $A$ to be a diagonal matrix.